# How to design an experiment to test delayed causality?

Tags: experiment-design, causality

I want to test if quitting game A will make a user more likely to quit game B that's on the same platform (e.g. on Steam). Quitting game B because of dissatisfaction with game A might not happen in the same day, it might take a week or maybe even two.

Could you tell me how should I design the experiment and how to compute the sample size? Just looking for some direction so that I can do further research on my own.

Comment: How would you force someone to quit game A in your experiment?

Comment: I don't think forcing someone to quit is an option here.

Comment: So what kind of experiment did you have in mind, what would you randomize?

Comment: I don't have any experiment in mind, nor do I know what to randomize. Reading more about this it seems that without a variable to mediate, there is no solution, is that correct? Maybe Granger causality is my best option here?

Comment: You could perform an experiment here, the problem is that it might be financially harmful. You randomize an incentive for people to be dissastified with game A (make it buggy etc for the treatment group). This would be an instrument for quitting game A (some people would quit because of that) and then you could use an IV approach to measure the effect of quitting game A because of dissatisfaction on quitting game B. However, this would be a costly experiment, not sure if it's worth it in real scenario. You might want to try to make inferences with the observational data you have instead.